# Geometry nodes - correct rotation of objects on curve

Tags: mesh, edges, geometry-nodes

I am currently trying to make a "castle generator" using geometry nodes. I have succesfully put the cubes on the right edges, but their rotation is not according to the edges direction. This is how it looks now, you can see the wrong rotations on edges that are not 90 degrees. [image: Castle] **Does anybody know, how I could rotate them in the direction of the edge?** This is my node setup. The nodes on left decide if the edge is on top of the "castle", or its side / down.[image: Nodes]

**EDIT:** Here is new node system and result. Is there anything I could change for it to work properly?
[image: Nodes2]
[image: Castel2]

**EDIT 2:** Here is **solved** final node system and result.
[image: Finale node system]
[image: Final Castle]

Comment: Take a look at the Align Euler to vector node

Comment: Thank you, that partly helped, but some segments are still defective. Is there anything I could do wrong? (I have edited my question to include the current node system.)

Comment: Maybe, setting the *Pivot* to *Z* helps. Would be easier to say, if you could provide your blend file.

Comment: I tryed change the Pivot and Axis but nothing help. Here is my blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ppkWBI_oO8OYXE8GiCE4fqR4yon9P1A/view?usp=sharing. If you have time to try repare it i will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to devide the problem into pieces. Could you please give concrete examples of wrong oriented cubes? And could you please sketch how they should look like?

For example, let us set up the *Align Euler to Vector* node like this:

[image: Align Euler to Vector with Pivot = Z]

If you take a look at the small cubes, then they look like this:

[image]

And from the top:

[image]

Is this, what you aim for? Or should they not be aligned to Z. Or do you want the cubes on the corners to be aligned differently?

[image: Cubes on the corners]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on your answer i solved it. I added another node for align euler on vector and now it works as i wished.